# How can you change what \frame{\sectionpage} does in beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I am using `beamer` to make a presentation. I would like to have a page after I start a new section with only the section title on it. When I use the command

```
\frame{\sectionpage}
```

I end up getting a page saying "Section 1" and then "the section title". I would however like to only have "the section title" and remove "Section 1". How can I do this?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136972/beamer-change-section-1-or-remove-it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `\insertsection` command to get the current section name and fashion your own `sectionpage`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{Section name A}
\frame{\insertsection}
\section{Section name B in the frametitle}
\begin{frame}{\insertsection} \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To modify the current one you can look up for the `\AtBeginSection` in the manual p.97 (v.3.12)

Answer (score 21):

I tailored my own template for the section page by using `\setbeamertemplate` and stripping the unneeded part from the original `\defbeamertemplate*{section page}` in `beamer/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}
}
```